# RaspBMC streaming music or audio

Tags: raspbmc, streaming-video

Is there any way of listening streams from different pages from XBMC, for example Mixify, Twitch, etc.

Comment: Using Mashup XBMC is very good source http://www.mashupxbmc.com/ for Many Sources of Streams

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a Twitch add-on, which allows you to watch streams Form Twitch. You can find it [here](http://addons.xbmc.org/show/plugin.video.twitch/).

Comment: Welcome to Raspberry Pi Stack Exchange! While we are glad you are getting involved in the conversation and are trying to be a part of the community, this answer is very poor quality. You simply state that there is an add-on without telling what it is or where you can get it. If you would like to keep this answer, please edit it to include a link to the add-on or even just the name. Thanks!